# Google map touch on bottom sheet dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, bottom-sheet

I have a google map fragment on the top of my bottom sheet dialog. I disabled the draggable touch action on the bottom sheet behavior so that I could control the map. The problem is that I can't scroll the map using up or down touch actions because of my bottom sheet draggable disabled. I was thinking to disable the touch action of the bottom sheet behavior when the user touches the map but I don't know how to do this. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I just used a DialogFragment for this. It works fine

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` to the bottom sheet layout:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` (parent `View`) that contains `SupportMapFragment` (child `View`). Panning the map works only for horizontal gestures. As OP mentioned, this is because `BottomSheet` and `Map` touch events are in conflict when it comes to vertical gestures.

This is how I handled it. My `BottomSheetDialogFragment` implements `OnMapReadyCallback` and `GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener`.

```
override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap) {
    p0.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(this)
}

override fun onCameraMoveStarted(reason: Int) {
    when(reason) {
        GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE -> {
            // The user gestured on the map
            childView?.parent?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        }
        GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_API_ANIMATION -> {
            // The user tapped something on the map
            childView?.parent?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        }
        GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_DEVELOPER_ANIMATION -> {
            // The app moved the camera
            childView?.parent?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        }
    }
}
```

When set as `true`, `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()` does not allow the parent `View` to intercept with the touch events of the child `View`. I can now zoom in/out the map (horizontal and vertical gestures) in my bottom sheet dialog fragment.

Comment: what is 'view'. always give full info

Answer (score 0):

I added **android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"** to the FragmentContainerView holding my Google map.

Now, I can maneuver in the Google map and use my Bottom Sheet normally.

```
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_bg" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Add Google Maps map fragment into `LinearLayout` and add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` this line into `LinearLayout`.