# Google Map view inside a bottom sheet

Tags: android, google-maps, bottom-sheet

I want to make a view like 
[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuMz1.png)

in which a want to show google maps inside a bottom sheet fragment.

**What I've tried**

I've tried to show maps inside a bottom sheet dialog fragment but the output isn't what I desire.

What I require is a fixed size view which should be able to display maps. Currently my view is also responding to user gestures to change bottom sheet state but I require gestures to work on map only (e.g for map panning).

Comment: on a past project I created something similar using MapBox and bottom sheet. I found this guide to helpful: https://medium.com/@emrullahluleci/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066

In your case you'd want the `bottom_sheet_content` to be your google map

Comment: Is there an other way you can suggest instead of bottom sheet?

Comment: @HamzaAhmedKhan Did you find the solution? Actually, I have also similar kind of functionality. If you have found a solution, please share. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

When we use the map on `BottomSheet`, it conflicts touch events. So, need to disallow touch of `BottomSheet`.

Please find a below custom class which allows the map to move.

```
public class BottomSheetMapView extends MapView {

public BottomSheetMapView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public BottomSheetMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public BottomSheetMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public BottomSheetMapView(Context context, MapboxMapOptions options) {
    super(context, options);
}
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}
```

}

I am using Mapbox. So, I use `com.example.BottomSheetMapView` instead of `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView` in xml. Similarly, you can use Google map.

This satisfies your requirement.

Comment: My friend, what you posted here is magical! Don't forget that you help a lot of devs with this solution. Thank you so much! I've been on an issue regarding this subject since 1 week.

Answer (score 0):

I need to implement the same feature. In my case, I used a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` that contains `SupportMapFragment`. The problem was, I could only make horizontal gestures on the map like panning it, but not vertical gestures. What needs to be done is to disable the `BottomSheet`'s touch listener while the user is doing some gestures on the map. You can refer to my similar post here to see how it should be done https://stackoverflow.com/a/53740355/1767167

Comment: ur answer is not complete