# Bottom sheet not working with google map

Tags: java, android

Map is moving when I try to close this BottomSheet by swap

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="40dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I must to do? I want like Google Map.
I try to set OnclickListener, but I can use BottomSheet in bottom only.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

This is onCreate()

Comment: show your java code

Comment: @Riddhi i did it

Comment: try following this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35793897/3342570 or this https://codingmountain.com/google-map-android-application-ui-clone-using-bottomsheet-layout/

Comment: Where is your BottomSheets's code?

Comment: @Riddhi codingmountian has got the shittiest kind of ads. it sucks

Comment: @HarKal what is it? i dont know!

Comment: @Riddhi check that link above u gave
if u want to earn then earn right way, never compromise user experience

Comment: @Riddhi have good day

Comment: @HarKal i dont know whats wrong with the link.. but at that time i followed the tutorial which i found online and i just shared the link. but i dont know why its showing like this now.

Comment: @Riddhi ok no prob. i just thought that you are the owner of the link. have good day

Comment: @HarKal no-no. I am not the owner. it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Looks similar to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541215/5444665)

Try adding `nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` to the bottom sheet layout:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
```